How to fix lifetime error in closure accepting a reference and returning an unboxed future?
I have a function that needs to accept an async closure. Since those are not yet supported, I am emulating them using a closure that returns a future. Simplifying my actual code, I have a function that looks like this:
pub async fn serve_request(
    request: Vec<u8>,
    dispatch: impl FnOnce(&[u8]) -> impl Future<Output = Vec<u8>> + Send>>,
) {
    // in actual code, other work is done before and after the dispatch
    dispatch(&request).await;
}

This doesn't compile because impl return from impl trait is not yet supported either. A simple fix is to return a boxed future:
pub async fn serve_request_1(
    request: Vec<u8>,
    dispatch: impl FnOnce(&[u8]) -> Pin<Box<dyn Future<Output = Vec<u8>> + Send + '_>>,
) {
    dispatch(&request).await;
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    tokio::spawn(serve_request_1(vec![], |payload| {
        Box::pin(async { payload.to_vec() })
    }));
}

Playground
The above compiles, but do note that it requires + '_ on the returned future, which is apparently shorthand for the higher-ranked trait bounds, impl for<'a> FnOnce(&'a [u8]) -> Pin<Box<dyn Future<Output = Vec<u8>> + Send + 'a>>, which also compiles.
Now I'd like to make it nicer (and more efficient) by not requiring Box::pin() around the async block. While returning impl Future from impl FnOnce doesn't compile, I thought I could replace the inner impl with a generic, like this:
pub async fn serve_request_2<Fut: Future<Output = Vec<u8>> + Send>(
    request: Vec<u8>,
    dispatch: impl FnOnce(&[u8]) -> Fut,
) {
    dispatch(&request).await;
}

This function compiles in isolation, but when you try to actually use it with a closure, it fails complaining about the lifetime in the return type of the closure. (Playground.)
Obvious attempts to fix it didn't work:
// doesn't compile because it's not HRTB
pub async fn serve_request_2<'a, Fut: Future<Output = Vec<u8>> + Send + 'a>(
    request: Vec<u8>,
    dispatch: impl FnOnce(&'a [u8]) -> Fut,
) {
    dispatch(&request).await;
}

// not valid: "undeclared lifetime 'a"
pub async fn serve_request_2<Fut: Future<Output = Vec<u8>> + Send + 'a>(
    request: Vec<u8>,
    dispatch: impl for<'a> FnOnce(&'a [u8]) -> Fut,
) {
    dispatch(&request).await;
}

// not valid: "'_ cannot be used here"
pub async fn serve_request_2<Fut: Future<Output = Vec<u8>> + Send + '_>(
    request: Vec<u8>,
    dispatch: impl FnOnce(&[u8]) -> Fut,
) {
    dispatch(&request).await;
}

I am unable to constrain Fut with the lifetime 'a of for<'a> FnOnce(&'a [u8]) -> Fut, which was possible with the Box<dyn Future>. Am I missing something, is it possible to do this?

The future returned by dispatch MUST be able to capture the lifetime of its argument. Because of that fact the future type must be something which mentions the lifetime like Future <...> + Send + 'a. But the lifetime cannot possibly be bound by the serve_request function because its a lifetime which is introduced in the body of the serve_request function (its the lifetime of a parameter). Without higher kinded types, your options are to replace the FnOnce with a custom trait; or to just use FnOnce(Vec<u8>) ->... (ie move the value into the future to avoid this issue entirely)

... the type you actually would want is for<'a> FnOnce(&'a [u8]) -> Fut<'a> where Fut : for <'a> Future<Output = Vec<u8>> + Send + 'a>. This Fut is a higher kinded type, but it is not valid syntax (rust doesn't yet support it).

@user2407038 Thanks. I'm still struggling to understand why it is not a problem to express it when the future is boxed.

There is no deep, fundamental reason for why higher kinded types are not supported. It's just something which is not implemented in the compiler, likely because it adds a lot of complexity esp. in the type system. It has nothing to do with the box-ed-ness of the future, it has to do with a signature quantifying over types and lifetimes (supported), vs. a signature quantifying over type-formers (not supported).

Higher kinded types are possible (https://docs.rs/lending-iterator/latest/lending_iterator/higher_kinded_types/index.html). Unfortunately, to use them, the type needs to be named. But most futures have an anonymous type. The box gets around the problem by naming the future using dyn: Pin<Box<dyn Future<Output = Vec<u8>> + Send + '_>>.

@trueequalsfalse Will it become possible to name the future types (in a way useful for this purpose) once type_alias_impl_trait lands?

@user4815162342 I don't know much about that feature, so I can't answer that.
